How do I configure the retention period for grafana loki using the microk8s observability add-on
How do I configure the retention period for grafana loki using the microk8s observability add-on?
Using microk8s 1.29.x with the following addons:
microk8s enable community
microk8s add observability
microk8s add hostpath-storage
I can't find the Loki config and the Grafana Loki documentation is not clear either on the microk8s part: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/storage/retention/
